# Vaadin 8 - Video Component Does Not Load Or Delays Loading

Tags: java, vaadin8

I have a simple method below that tries to play a conventional Video component. When trying to load a video using an ExternalResource (the videos come from either Youtube or an external link of another website) in a Window component, the window result behaves differently. For example, in Edge browsers, the video will simply will not load but with the play / pause controls are visible. In Firefox, the loading cursor keeps running forever. (note that HtmlContentAllowed flag is turned on)

```
protected void loadVideoWindow(String url){
  Window subWindow = new Window();
  subWindow.setSizeFull();
  subWindow.setModal(true);
  subWindow.setResizable(false);

  Video video = new Video("Video",new ExternalResource("https://youtu.be/xxxx")); //url string will be used here 
  video.setWidth("600px");
  video.setHeight("600px");
  video.setHtmlContentAllowed(true);

  subWindow.setContent(video);
  UI.getCurrent().addWindow(subWindow);
}
```

If there's indeed a known problem without a workaround of running external videos using that method above, is it better to move to loading another tab / url link and play the video instead?

I also noticed that there are two known addons: SWF and the AudioVideo addon. The former seems to be very old, while for the latter, can the ExternalResource be used or it needs to be converted to a ClassResource first (as seen in the example)?

Answer (score 1):

The `Video` component is based on the `<video>` HTML element which is implemented natively by browsers. It supports various regular video files such as `.avi` and `.mp4`, but it doesn't support videos straight from streaming services such as YouTube.

If you want to embed a YouTube video, then you need to embed that using YouTube's own player. The easiest way is probably to use their `<iframe>` [embedding option](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Manual_IFrame_Embeds) together with the corresponding Vaadin component. There are some add-ons in Vaadin Directory that claim to to this, but I don't have personal experience with any of them.